# How to access the custom user values from Django template in logged in state?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-users

I am trying to access the user from template but
its showing anonymous user on printing the `{{ user }}` or `{{ request.user }}`.

I want to set the name in header of the site but always get the name empty. Please find below the snippet:

```
class LoginFormView(View):
    form_class = UserLoginForm
    user_model=get_user_model()
    template_name='account/login.html'

    def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        form=self.form_class
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form':form})

    def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        email = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Please enter correct email and password!')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER','/'))
```

Custom User model:

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **kwargs):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have a valid email address.')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email), full_name=kwargs.get('full_name')
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()

        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **kwargs):
        user = self.create_user(email, password, **kwargs)
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save()

        return user

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True, null=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True, null=True)
    about = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=1, default='U')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['full_name']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.full_name

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.full_name
```

Comment: Has the user authenticated?

Comment: Yes..first authenticated and then login

Comment: Are you using a custom authentication backend or the default one? Please update the question with the code where you are performing the login in your view.

Comment: I am using the default one.

Comment: Where is the view code? Are you passing the user in the context?

Comment: What is your `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` in settings.py?

Comment: Added code for custom user model. I am using the default  AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS ('django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',)

Comment: @aldux I have already shared my view code.

Answer (score 0):

The default authentication backend in Django is the `'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'`, which uses `username` and `password` to authenticate. [(link to the Docs)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/)

If you are using this authentication backend, your view is not successfully authenticating the user, which would result in returning an instance of `AnonymousUser`, which will never None. Therefore, your view will never return the error message.

In order to authenticate with the `email` field, you need to write a custom backend (you can find examples on Google) or to install one of the multiple apps that provide this backend.

Answer (score 0):

**You are trying to authenticate using `email` but the default authentication backend does not allow us to authenticate via `email`.**

From the docs on [`authenticate()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.authenticate) function:

> It takes credentials in the form of keyword arguments, for the default
>   configuration this is `username` and `password`, and it returns a `User`
>   object if the password is valid for the given `username`.

**So, we need to implement our own Email authentication backend.**

You can do something like below:

**Step-1 Substite the custom User model in settings:**

Since we would not be using Django's default `User` model for authentication, we need to define our custom `MyUser` model in `settings.py`. Specify `MyUser` as the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in the project's settings.

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.MyUser'
```

**Step-2 Write the logic for the custom email authentication backend:**

To write our own authentication backend, we need to implement atleast two  methods i.e. `get_user(user_id)` and `authenticate(**credentials)`.

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.models import check_password

class MyEmailBackend(object):
    """
    Custom Email Backend to perform authentication via email
    """
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        my_user_model = get_user_model()
        try:
            user = my_user_model.objects.get(email=username)
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user # return user on valid credentials
        except my_user_model.DoesNotExist:
            return None # return None if custom user model does not exist 
        except:
            return None # return None in case of other exceptions

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        my_user_model = get_user_model()
        try:
            return my_user_model.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except my_user_model.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

**Step-3 Specify the custom authentication backend in settings:**

After writing the custom authentication backend, specify this authentication backend in the `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` setting.

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'my_app.backends.MyEmailBackend', # our custom authentication backend
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But in my user model, I have specified the username field to use email column. Shouldn't it work then?

Comment: Are you using a custom user model? Also, please post the code where you have specified the username field to use email column.

Comment: I have already pasted the code above. USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

Comment: I have done all the above mentioned changes. I am getting "ImportError at /

No module named MyEmailBackend"

Comment: Please post the traceback. There must be a `backends.py` file in your `my_app` app having the class `MyEmailBackend`.

Comment: `File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
  396.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py" in import_module
  37.     __import__(name)
File "/home/vaio/git_kiti/kiti/kiti/urls.py" in <module>
  18. from account.views import forgot
File "/home/vaio/git_kiti/kiti/account/views.py" in <module>
  12. from account.backends.MyEmailBackend import authenticate`

Comment: In your views, import Django's `authenticate()`  which will itself call the `authenticate()` function of your backend i.e `from django.contrib.auth import authenticate`

Comment: Yes, as you mentioned the flow is going there...But still in my template,  {{ user }} is showing AnonymousUser like before.

Comment: In your views, change  `user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)` to `user = authenticate(username=email, password=password)`

Comment: This time, it didn't even went to the custom authenticate method as the signatures of both (function call and function definition) are different.

Comment: How are they different? they both have `username` and `email` as arguments. Please check if the correct value has been passed to it. Also, try putting debugger above `authenticate()` function in your view and see what is happening.

Comment: Yes, I commented after debugging the flow. In case of authenticate(email=email, password=password), both the default functions are being called and in case of authenticate(username=email, password=password), only default is getting called. Also, both (default and custom auth methods are running successfully. I think, I am missing something after login before doing HttpResponseRedirect.

Comment: Are you getting the correct user after `authenticate()`? If yes, check if the user is `active`. Try to go into `login()` function and see what is happening.

Comment: I printed the user after login. Its showing the email and in debugger, its showing all the other attributes of User object with correct values.

Comment: Please check the `login()` function in your view using debugger and see if it setting the `request.user` to your user.

Comment: No, its not setting. user object is getting set but not request.user

Comment: Check if `user.is_active` is `True`

Comment: Yes, it is. Its going into login only after that. I have already pasted the view code above in question.